# The canonical automorphism of the symmetric group

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, lie-algebras, terminology, symmetric-groups

Let $S_n$ be the symmetric group of order $n$. Denoting simple transpositions by $\sigma_i$ the collection $\sigma_1, \dots, \sigma_{n-1}$ generates $S_n$ subject to the following relations:
$$
\sigma _{i}^{2}=1,
$$

$$
\sigma _{i}\sigma _{j} = \sigma _{j}\sigma _{i} \textrm{ for } |i-j| > 1 
$$

$$
\sigma_{i}\sigma_{i+1}\sigma_{i} = \sigma_{i+1}\sigma_{i}\sigma_{i+1}.
$$
From these relations we see a group automorphism  $\alpha:S_n \to S_n$ is given by
$$
\alpha(\sigma_i) = \sigma_{n-i}.
$$
Does this automorphism have a name? In fact this can be seen as a special case of the automorphism the $A$-series Weyl group coming from the obvious automorphism of the $A$-Dynkin diagram. Such (non-trivial) automorphisms exist in other series (D_n,E_6), hence perhaps there is a name at this level of generality?

Comment: Since $S_n$ is complete (most of the time), this must be an inner automorphism. Thus it must be conjugation by a canonical element, given a choice of generating transpositions. Chances are, it is conjugation by the longest element: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1666717/what-is-the-longest-element-of-s-n-as-a-product-of-adjacent-transpositions. Indeed, it is:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59783/properties-of-the-longest-element-in-a-weyl-group

Comment: Without Coxeter point of view, one can see directly that it's conjugation by the permutation $i\mapsto n+1-i$ (assuming that $\sigma_i$ transposes $i\leftrightarrow i+1$).

Comment: In defence of the Coxeter point of view, the second linked discussion also addresses the question in other types, which was also asked by OP.

Comment: For the corresponding automorphism of the Dynkin diagram, it seems the most common name is the "opposition involution", as I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4516128/what-is-the-name-of-the-duality-dynkin-diagram-automorphism)

Comment: @Callum: Fantastic! That is what I was loking for!